# Concurrency iterating over NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, concurrency, queue

I've an `array` of user objects. I need to iterate over this array, and then, for each user, I need to make a request to fetch data, based on its user id. This request is an async request (and for reasons I can't make it sync). Here is the edited code using dispatch_group calls:

EDITED

```
for (User *user in self.userList) {
    dispatch_group_enter(self.usersGroup);
    [self.wrapper getUserDataWithId:user.userid completion:^(Owner *owner, NSError *error) {
        user.owner = owner;
        dispatch_group_leave(self.usersGroup);
    }];
}

dispatch_group_notify(self.usersGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   // All requests have finished
   // Stuff with updated userlist
});
```

The main issue is obvious: when first requests have finished, the user reference it has is not the one that has launched the request, so I don't have the correct association.

Is there any easy and elegant way to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The block will capture the value of `user`, so the owner will be set on the right object. How are you waiting until all requests are finished?

Comment: The block only knows about an id (string) but has no reference to user object. I'm tried with dispatch_group which waits until all requests have finished, but returned array has no correlative data

Comment: Adding the code you tried using dispatch groups would help people help you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Paulw11 suggested the loop will not wait for you to execute the block so i'm suggesting you to use recursive function like this instead of for loop.

```
- (void)getOwnerForObectAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    if (index < self.userList) {
        User *user = [self.userList objectAtIndex:index];
        [self.wrapper getUserDataWithId:user.userid completion:^(Owner *owner, NSError *error) {
            user.owner = owner;
            [self getOwnerForObectAtIndex:index+1];
        }];
    }
    else {
        //Now all User have its corresponding owner, Handle array Now. 
    }
}
```

Now call this function like this `[self getOwnerForObectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: I tried using dispatch_group but maybe a recursive function is better solution. Thanks!!

Comment: The OPs loop will finish after an asynchronous task has been started for each element, your recursive solution will return after an asynchronous task has been started for the first element, neither will wait for all tasks to finish as the OP wishes.

Comment: @CRD No this will work as of I am calling my function again after he got response check properly. Block statement only execute if he get responses.

Comment: The OP needs to process the array **after** all the async tasks have finished. How does your code achieve that?

Comment: @CRD Check edit, It just need to add one else block for that.

Comment: That is better, but would not using a completion block be more flexible? Also while the OPs approach handled the tasks concurrently your approach handles them sequentially - that isn't "wrong" of course but could make a significant difference so Is worth noting.

Comment: @NDoc It works, but it takes too long to finish all requests. What I need is to make all requests at the same time, but keeping reference to the User object that creates the request, in order to update its data. By using dispatch_group I already know when all requests have finished.